# Comparing two object variables using sort() within a vector

Tags: c++, pointers, object, vector

I have been banging my head against this and google for a while now so I hope it is alright to ask. I am still learning C++ and enjoying it but I don't full understand everything yet and am really just now digging into pointers and classes in my Data Structures class. Why can I not compare the fitness variables of the tree objects using this sort?

I am getting the error: 'Environment::compare': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member.

```
void Environment::evolve(const int popsize,const int maxgen) {
    std::cout << "> evolving function" << std::endl;

    std::vector<Tree> popvec;

    // Generate initial pop trees and store in array
    for (int i = 0; i <= popsize - 1; i++) {
        std::cout << "> generating initial population" << std::endl;

        Tree membertree;
        popvec.push_back(membertree);
    }

    // Loop for generations
    for (int j = 1; j <= maxgen; j++) {
        std::cout << "Generation " << j << ":" << std::endl;

        // sort array by fitness
        std::sort(popvec.begin(), popvec.end(), compare);

        // cull herd

        // reproduce

    }
}

bool Environment::compare(Tree obj1, Tree obj2) {
    return (obj1.fitness < obj2.fitness);
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Edit with header:

```
#include "Tree.h"

class Environment {
public:
    Environment();
    ~Environment();
    void evolve(const int popsize,const int maxgen);
    bool compare(Tree obj1, Tree obj2);

private:
    Tree* poparray;
};
```

Comment: `Environment::compare` should be `static`. Show your header, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The immediate cause of compile error

```
std::sort(popvec.begin(), popvec.end(), compare);
```

You're referencing `compare`, which is a class member function. To pass a pointer to class member (data or function) you need to use the `&Class::Member` syntax:

```
std::sort(popvec.begin(), popvec.end(), &Environment::compare);
```

But this won't work unless `compare` is a static function - as it should be (or you can do gymnastics with passing a stateful lambda/functor, but there's no reason a sane person would do this).

## The real problem

You should change declaration of `compare` - make it a `static` member function:

```
static bool compare(Tree obj1, Tree obj2);
```

If you do this, changing the `sort` call syntax is no longer necessary (although still valid)

Comment: `static` alone is sufficient. You don't need to use the `&Class::Member` syntax here; the `&` is optional and the `Class::`  is implied in the context of other members. A pointer to a static member isn't the same as [pointer-to-member](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_member_functions).

Comment: @JasonC see the edit

Comment: What pointer am I passing to it?

Comment: `compare` decays into pointer-to-function (if `compare` is static member function or free function)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to declare `Environment::compare` as `static`, e.g.:

```
class Environment {
    ...
    static bool compare (Tree obj1, Tree obj2);
    ...
};
```

Comment: Thank you that seems to have worked!